# Cross-compile SDL2 from linux to Windows doesn't make an exe

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cmake, sdl-2

I am using a WSL running Ubuntu and am trying to get an SDL2 program to compile using the Ubuntu and then run the program on Windows. I have been able to get it to build, however it doesn't make an exe (and changing the file extension to exe doesn't fix it). Also even though I set the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to have -o Crawl_The_Dungeon.exe the file still ends up being named all lower case like the project name. I was able to get this to compile and run on linux when I still had a linux machine.

I am still pretty new to CMake so I don't fully understand if I am close at all or not at all.

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)            # Enable c++14 standard
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${crawl_the_dungeon_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakePath")

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
project(crawl_the_dungeon)
set(SOURCE_FILES final.cpp Soldier.cpp TilesEnum.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --static -std=c++0x")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(crawl_the_dungeon ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
                             ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
                             ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
                             )

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc")
```

EDIT: I was dumb to include -o Crawl_The_Dungeon.exe as it now creates an exe. However it says that I can't run the program when opening it.

Comment: I was dumb to include -o Crawl_The_Dungeon.exe as it now creates an exe. However it says that I can't run the program when opening it.

Comment: What does the output of `file yourexecutable` output on WSL? I guess that would be `file Crawl_The_Dungeon`. I suspect you are creating an ELF executable. Or, per your comment, if it is producing a windows exe `Crawl_The_Dungeon.exe` then what is output when you attempt to run it from the command prompt in windows?

Comment: In the WSL I get error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment. When trying to run in CMD I get cannot start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of windows

Comment: I have gotten it to create an exe now. It just won't run

Comment: Unless you have the new release of windows 21H1, you won't be able to run it in WSL (no X), but I was curious about the `file ...` output to see what WSL thinks it created. Just because the executable was created with the extension `.exe` doesn't mean it is a windows executable. If you are cross compiling in WSL, then do you also have the SDL libraries on the windows side? You compile with `--static` to use the static SDL libraries (should be `libsdl.a` somewhere), you need that on the windows side as well.

Comment: Doing ```file``` I get ```crawl_the_dungeon.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=9f1986db5a178c0a754f83a3566901f465ca8761, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped```


I have updated the file here and in my code to be statically linked because I don't want to have the libraries in windows, but now I get ```attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2.so```

Comment: If you don't have the static library for SDL2, (`libsdl2.a`), then you are left to use the shared-object library. The rub is this. You have created an ELF executable. Linux [Executable and Linkable Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)

Comment: Interesting. Where in CMake do I decide what file format I am making? Also I found libsdl2.a in the same folder as libsdl2.so so I am a bit confused as to why it is picking .so

Comment: This is where you have to slow down and ask "What toolchains do I have installed on windows and what do I have in WSL?" Generally, unless you install an explicit cross-compile tool chain, windows compiles windows executeables and Linux compiles ELF. MinGW on windows is gcc with an explicit cross-compile toolchain that allows MinGW (gcc) to produce windows executables. In WSL you would need a similar toolchain, or the ability to use the MinGW installed on the windows side. (I haven't used WSL to compile for windows, never needed to, so others will have to help there)